# Using jQuery to add/remove class depending on which radio button is checked

Tags: jquery, html

I have two radio buttons. When one radio is checked, it needs to add a class to the other radios label. And when it is unchecked, remove that class. Sounds simple enough but I can't seem to het it working. I have a plunker example here [Plunker Code](http://embed.plnkr.co/Gvfz9qStOmawO3xrrdH7/preview)

```
 <form name="backgroundPanelForm" novalidate="novalidate" role="form">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row radio-set background-radio-labels">
            <div class="radio">
                <input type="radio" data-ng-click="backgroundCtrl.switchPanel('uploadImage')" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" data-ng-class="{uploadImageActive : backgroundCtrl.showPanel == 'uploadImage'}" value="uploadImage" data-ng-model="backgroundCtrl.uploadImage">
                <label class="choose-image" for="optionsRadios1">
                    <span></span>upload images
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <input type="radio" data-ng-click="backgroundCtrl.switchPanel('chooseExisting')" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" data-ng-class="{chooseExistingActive : backgroundCtrl.showPanel == 'chooseExisting'}" data-ng-change="backgroundCtrl.switchPanel('chooseExisting');" value="chooseExisting" data-ng-model="backgroundCtrl.chooseExisting">
                <label class="choose-existing" for="optionsRadios2">
                    <span></span>choose existing
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-ng-switch="backgroundCtrl.showPanel">
            <div data-ng-switch-when="uploadImage" class="app-branding-animate">
                <div data-ng-include="'components/appGateway/branding/panels/background-upload-image.html'"></div>
            </div>
            <div data-ng-switch-when="chooseExisting" class="app-branding-animate">
                <div data-ng-include="'components/appGateway/branding/panels/background-choose-existing.html'"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript is:

```
jQuery("input#optionsRadios1:radio").click(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                $('label.choose-existing').addClass('radio-disabled');
            } else if (!this.checked){
                $('label.choose-existing').removeClass('radio-disabled');
            }
        });


        jQuery("input#optionsRadios2:radio").click(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                $('label.choose-image').addClass('radio-disabled');
            } else if (!this.checked){
                $('label.choose-image').removeClass('radio-disabled');
            }

        });



CSS:
.radio-disabled {
  color: #d3d3d3;
   }
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Please, post your code to work on it.

Comment: Does your javascript code between `<script>` tags? And `this.checked` is not good I think. It should be `if ($(this).is(':checked')) {`

Comment: In your plunker example it looks like you've got the includes the wrong way round. You need to include Jquery before you include the bootstrap js file

Comment: And you has on error on your page: `Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery` It seems, jQuery does not loaded.

Comment: Its not actually removing the class though if it is checked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your script file added in the page head, so you need to have your script inside dom ready handler, else when the script is executed the radio elements are not added to the dom, so the click handlers will not get registered.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#optionsRadios1:radio").click(function () {
        $('label.choose-existing').toggleClass('radio-disabled', this.checked);
    });

    $("#optionsRadios2:radio").click(function () {
        $('label.choose-image').addClass('radio-disabled', this.checked);
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/mAddPvaH6ZKWdAYSMOPm?p=preview)

---

Also note that since bootstrap required jQuery, you need to include jQuery before boostrap

```
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

---

A simplified version is

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $radios = $('input[name="optionsRadios"]').click(function () {
        $(this).next().removeClass('radio-disabled');
        $radios.not(this).next().addClass('radio-disabled');
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lr2w4j0h/)

Comment: Its not actually removing the class though if it is checked

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need ( also notice on the code difference):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("input[name = 'optionsRadios']").click(function() {
            if ($(this).val() === "uploadImage") {
                $('label.choose-existing').addClass('radio-disabled');
                $('label.choose-image').removeClass('radio-disabled');
            } else {
                $('label.choose-existing').removeClass('radio-disabled');
        $('label.choose-image').addClass('radio-disabled');
            }
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#optionsRadios1').is(':checked')) { 
     $('label.choose-image').addClass('radio-disabled');
}
 else if($('#optionsRadios2').is(':checked')) { 
     $('label.choose-image').addClass('radio-disabled');
}
else {
       // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( "input:radio[name=optionsRadios]" ).on( "click", function() {
     $('label.choose-image,label.choose-existing').removeClass('radio-disabled');
    if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() === "uploadimage") {
       $('label.choose-existing').addClass('radio-disabled');
     } else {
             $('label.choose-image').addClass('radio-disabled');
     }
   });
});
```